# Installing ceres-solver on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, c++11, ceres-solver

running `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=ceres-solver/cmake/iOS.cmake  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-stdlib=libc++" -DEIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/eigen -DIOS_PLATFORM=OS ceres-solver`

gives me these errors

```
-- Using minimal glog substitute (include): internal/ceres/miniglog
-- Max log level for minimal glog substitute: 2
-- Building without OpenMP, disabling.
-- Neither OpenMP or TBB is enabled, disabling multithreading.
-- Looking for C++ include unordered_map
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM" "cmTC_3feba/fast"
-- Looking for C++ include unordered_map - not found
-- Looking for C++ include tr1/unordered_map
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM" "cmTC_36cb7/fast"
-- Looking for C++ include tr1/unordered_map - not found
-- Unable to find <unordered_map> or <tr1/unordered_map>.
-- Replacing unordered_map/set with map/set (warning: slower!), try enabling CXX11 option if you expect C++11 to be available.
-- Looking for C++ include memory
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM" "cmTC_013b8/fast"
-- Looking for C++ include memory - not found
-- Looking for C++ include tr1/memory
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM" "cmTC_bb377/fast"
-- Looking for C++ include tr1/memory - not found
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:494 (message):
  Unable to find shared_ptr, try enabling CXX11 option if you expect C++11 to
  be available.
```

even if i set CXX11 ON, I would get the same error. What should I do?

Assuming I get this working, do I just run `make install` to get the `libceres.a` file?

Much help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a C++11 error, notice the error

CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM" "cmTC_3feba/fast"

CMake is trying to determine the presence of various c++11 features by compiling several short program fragments, and is unable to do so, due to some Make related problems (do you have make installed? Xcore command line tools?) and it ends up concluding that c++11 is not available.

The thing to fix here is to see what is going on with Make on your system.